# How to get this kind of effect (transparent and illuminating) using blender shader node?

Tags: rendering, materials

How to get this kind of effect (transparent and illuminating) using blender shader node?

[image]

this is from the overwatch game cg.

Comment: impossible to see your picture

Comment: Please re-upload your pictures.